# MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL consuming over 70% of memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory

- SQL Server 2014 SP2 Enterprise Core bases License (64 bit)
- CPU (logical) = 32
- Memory 128GB
- SQL Server Max Memory : 100GB

We see that more than 70% is taken by `MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL`. I see only 300 sessions (50 active). We are having memory contention and we see that plan cache is floored and Page Life Expectancy also going down.

```
           type                            Page Allocator (MB)
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL                     71194
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL                         26459
```

`DBCC MemoryStatus` output:

```
Memory Manager                           KB
Emergency Memory                         1024
Emergency Memory In Use                  16
Target Committed                         104857608
Current Committed                        104626984

MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (node 0)   KB
Pages Allocated                          34,733,992
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (node 1)   KB
Pages Allocated                          37,559,224
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (Total)    KB
Pages Allocated                          72,293,216
```

Please help me with next steps to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Add the output of select @@version in the question, just to be clear. Also can you show me the query you used to get the output

Comment: Do you have a lot of Databases and/or Logins that access the Instance? How many app servers are connecting? Any desktop applications accessing it?